# 512 bits integer on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I would like to know how to create 512 bits integer and is there a lib for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @Ziggamorph - the applications for large numbers are quite varied.  Cryptography, for example, usually requires the use of enormously large integers.

Comment: Can't help but hear the "there's an app for that" phrase when the op says "is there a lib for that?" hehe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html) class can be used to represent very large numbers.  If you can figure out how to link against the openssl library on the iPhone, then you can use my [CHMath.framework](http://github.com/davedelong/chmath) wrappers around the OpenSSL BigNumber functions.